# how do I retrieve attributes of different models from controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Vendor controller for show:

```
def show
@vendor = Vendor.find(params[:id])

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @vendor }
end
end
```

In my View for Reviews (where Vendor :has_many Reviews)

```
    <% if @vendor.reviews.empty? %>
        No Analyst Reports yet
    <% else %>
        <% for review in @vendor.reviews %>

            <%= review.user_id %>
            <%= review.summary %><br />
            <hr class="span-5" />

        <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

So I am basically going through a 'for' loop for all the reviews for a particular vendor (this has been a tricky concept for me but it seems to work).

So: I want to display the User.name and user.email.  I know what the user_id for each corresponding Review is (review.user_id) but I don't know how to display values for the User model.

I thought using find_by_id would work but it doesn't recognize User.

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've set up a `:has_one` relationship between the Review model and the User model, then you can just use `review.user` to access it.  So you'd get user attributes with `review.user.name`, `review.user.email`, etc.

Note that if you're going to be retrieving many child records to loop through like this, you may want to call `find` with an `:include` parameter to reduce the number of queries made.  Something like:

```
Vendor.find(params[:id], :include => { :reviews => :user } )
```

See the [API docs for has_one](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#M001790) for more info.

Comment: Hi, would I include the Vendor.find within the for-loop?  I created a ':has_many' relationship because a user has_many reviews.  Is that possible?

Comment: No, you don't need to call find more than once. Just add ":belongs_to :user" to your Review model to make their relationship work both ways.

Comment: yes, I already have a :belongs_to and review.user.name keeps saying that the value is 'nil'....let me play around with it.

Comment: It means to preload all the reviews and users at the same time as the vendor, which is faster than letting them load one-by-one as needed.  On the same documentation page I linked, the section above entitled "Eager loading of associations" explains it.